# Over The Air (OTA) iOS distribution

Tags: ios, xcode6

When distributing apps using OTA using Enterprise license.
What steps are to be followed?
How is the provisioning profile created, so it doesn't require any device Id?
 
How do I archive?
Coz I am not able to see my app in Organiser->archive, eventhough I have checked the option reveal in Archiver (in Edit Scheme).
What next?
I am using Xcode 6.01 and iOS SDK 8.1

Comment: If only there were some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW1) and [videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/enterprise/) that some company posted on their [developer site for enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any looking for the same answer. How exactly Over the air iOS app distribution is done.
It is actually in house app distribution with enterprise development program.

A good explanation is in the link below 
http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/